# How could an antimatter battery take the shaking and knocks from being in an active android?

Tags: technology, electromagnetism, antimatter

There are quite a few questions on here related to using antimatter-matter annihilations as an energy source or weapon and it seems one big issue is the safety issue of it not all going off if damaged.

As our current technology isn't anywhere advanced enough to produce enough and store antimatter some handwaving will be necessary but it will be a standard design of positrons suspended in an EM field, possible a lattice or honeycomb structure to keep positrons spaced in their chamber before being released for electron-positron annihilation.

I'm not worried about the battery itself being damaged from the outside and leaking, I am wondering if antimatter battery could withstand the shaking and knocks from an active android that engages hand to hand combat and acrobatics, as well as accelerating to high speeds with sudden stopping.

Given what we know of the requirements of storing antimatter, even though we aren't advanced enough yet and the idea does involve some hand waving, is there a way of knowing if all the rapid shaking of an antimatter battery would set it off or could it remain safe?

Comment: This is all up to speculation. You may want to have a very sturdy battery which tolerates big (reasonably big) shocks, or a more fragile one. From our current scientific understanding, either way is possible. But you need to address all kind of damage issues. If your robot is shot, can the battery explode?

Comment: @Alexander I was ignoring any damage to the battery in the way of being shot or something because I don't think a battery wall can be that strong, especially with the high powerd weapons in the story, and I don't mind the collateral damage if something so powerful does hit them and make the battery go off, its just the average bumps a soldier would take minus the kill shots.

Comment: Ok, just pay attention to this vulnerability, because one "kill shot" can generate a chain reaction, taking out all androids in a group and any nearby humans.

Comment: @Alexander I understand that, I was going to have them either be stealth or so good at dodging they don't get touched by bullets, either way they will be lone warriors and could be kamikaze if they want. but I want them to be able to engage in hand to hand combat.

Comment: I apologize, but VTC:OP. We have batteries that survive in tank warfare just fine, so the answer should be yes, but not *every* battery can do that - and since we don't know anything about antimatter batteries, the only valid answer is, "if you want it to, sure."

Comment: from personal experience hours ago at physic.se on similar topic, your question is most likely to be closed as opinion based ;D

Comment: Maybe ask this way:  Failure mode of concern is that the antimatter particles contained in the EM field will come into contact with the matter making up the internal physical components of the battery due to the battery being accelerated.  So maybe ask the question as "For an antimatter battery where particles are suspended x cm by an EM field from the internal wall of the battery which may be accelerated unexpectedly in any direction at up to y G for z seconds, are there any theoretical limits that would prevent the EM field from adjusting to keep the matter and antimatter apart?" more...

Comment: … can only ask about theoretical limits because, as noted by other comments, no one has built something like this before.  Answers could explore the power requirements and necessary response times and whether there is anything inherently impossible about these.

Comment: @JBH Tank batteries survive just fine because they are protected by tank armor. I don't think any battery by itself would survive a direct hit by tank round.

Comment: @Alexander that's not what the OP asked. He asked if a battery of a type could survive being in an active android. That would be similar to being in a moving tank, even a tank in combat (armor means nothing in this case) - but to suggest it wouldn't survive a direct hit would be to suggest that the android's battery couldn't either (and it wouldn't). I believe my principle point stands.

Comment: Why was this closed? Of course it's entirely speculative, but this isn't physics.se is it? Different opinions on how to make this work for OP's world should be encouraged, not disparaged imho.

Comment: @Douwe thats true it is discouraging when a question is closed so quickly and some of my recent questions have been close voted by new members also who shouldn't be so quick to close vote after an experienced member says they are..

Comment: @Douwe Good edit thanks, as KerrAvon2055 suggested also, concentrating on how to minimise the batteries movement and what the limits are would be good to know, as StephenG has answered I may pose that as its own question if it doesn't get re opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last time I was in a car I was sitting about two feet from tank full of petrol and an engine where it literally explodes in order for the engine to work.  If someone has the technology to build an anti-matter battery they would certainly have the technology to house it robustly because that kind of technology is much simpler than anti-matter production and storage.

> I am wondering if antimatter battery could withstand the shaking and knocks from an active android that engages hand to hand combat and acrobatics, as well as accelerating to high speeds with sudden stopping.

Any technology that that isolate anti-matter well enough from matter to be reliable and safe is not going to be in the least bit affected by something as trivial as you describe.

Anti-matter is a pretty insane material to use anyway as if you could make such a battery you basically have a walking nuke and it doesn't seem very useful for hand to hand combat when it's easier to just send them to wipe out the enemy by exploding.

One of the problems with anti-matter power sources would be that the power required to keep the anti-matter confined and controlled has to be available even if the anti-matter power source itself cannot provide power - you need a backup in case, e.g. the connection from AM power unit to the rest of the system is broken (as could easily happen in combat).  So you need an extremely powerful and reliable backup power source and that would be a better choice of primary power for the android in the first place (probably).  The backup power supply cannot be a backup in the sense of being activated when power cuts off - there won't be time to allow that if AM is involved.  So that "backup" will be always on and always powering the confinement system.

Any technological society able to make an AM battery could probably make a pretty good nuclear power source just as easily and it is a great deal easier to make these "fail safe" and robust.  I just cannot see a use for an AM battery in an android.

Comment: I see what your saying, thats why I hadn't committed to antimatter, if antimatter was safer it would be perfect for the over the top power I need my droids to have - how powerful do you think a brick sized fussion reactor could theoretically pump out?

Comment: @RandySavage I'd suggest asking that as a separate question - it's probably a good enough question in it's own right, IMO.  Note : power generated and problematic heat to dissipate are closely related, so big power requires big cooling.

Comment: @RandySavage Just to mention that I usually recommend people wait at least one or two full days before accepting an answer as people from all over the planet come here and sometimes later posts can be better.

Comment: when I woke up and checked the question was closed and your answer was there, im not sure protocol of re-opened questions and honestly didn't think it would be re-opened, your answer helped enough that it deserved the credit of being accepted.

Comment: @RandySavage My mistake, I'd forgotten the question was closed.  It's not uncommon for closed questions to still have useful answers, so at least you got something from it.  Hopefully your nuclear battery question will fair better.